# How to custom field select options in register and saving them in db

Tags: magento2, custom-options, registration

I need to add select input in registration from in magento 2 I did all the steps but in InstallData.php file I have this partial code

```
  $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'account_type', [
        // Attribute parameters
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Account Type',
        'input' => 'select',
        'required' => true,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 990,
        'position' => 990,
        'system' => 0,
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'option' => ['values' => [1=>'Customer', 2=>'Designer or Architect']],
        'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
    ]);
```

I think it add select's options in db but it doesn't take values in right way it suppose to be `1` and `2` but it shows `4` and `5` like:

```
  <option data-title="Customer" value="4">Customer</option>
  <option data-title="Designer or Architect" value="5">Designer or Architect</option>
```

How to make this take the values I defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'account_type', [
        // Attribute parameters
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Account Type',
        'input' => 'select',
        'required' => true,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 990,
        'position' => 990,
        'system' => 0,
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'option' => ['values' => ['Customer', 'Designer or Architect']],
        'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
    ]);
```

Comment: try this in upgrade data hope it works let me know if any issues

Comment: `Customer` & `Designer or Architect` are option's labels I need to set values for them 1 and 2 not values 4 and 5 as showed previously

Comment: kindly let me know what you will be doing with values

Comment: each option has `value` and `text` I need to set option value not auto set